# Stored procedure to delete rows - SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: t-sql, stored-procedures, sql-server-2008-r2

I have written a stored procedure that only allowed to have 100 rows with same `CustomerPK`, so if we want to insert row 101, the oldest row with the same `CustomerPK` needs to be deleted.

I'm sure there are several ways of doing this and I'm not sure which one is best. Here is the code for the procedure.

```
DECLARE 
    @TokenCount INT;

SELECT 
    @TokenCount = COUNT(*)
FROM 
    CustomerAuthTokens
WHERE 
    CustomerPK = @CustomerPK;

IF @TokenCount > 99 
BEGIN
   DELETE FROM CustomerAuthTokens 
   WHERE AuthToken IN (SELECT TOP(@TokenCount - 99) AuthToken 
                       FROM CustomerAuthTokens 
                       WHERE CustomerPK = @CustomerPK
                       ORDER BY TokenCreateTime ASC);
END
```

Comment: Why not just update the oldest row, instead of insert/delete

Comment: @EricZ because oldest row may in some extreme cases not be row number 100

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
--Insert your row first


-- This will delete customer rows if there are more than 100 rows for that customer
;WITH cte as
(
SELECT row_number() over (partition by CustomerPK order by TokenCreateTime desc) rn 
FROM CustomerAuthTokens
WHERE CustomerPK = @CustomerPK
)
DELETE CTE
WHERE rn > 100
```